# Bash to read all columns and display blank cells in each row from CSV file

Tags: shell-script, csv

[image: EXAMPLE CSV]

I need the script to go through each column and check for blanks and group it up for me into 1 column... so e.g. 
1st row: **banana** , 2nd row: **rachel**, 5th row: **rachel, monica, chandler, joey, janice, banana**

Comment: Hello and welcome to UL SE. Can you please provide us an example CSV file, illustrating your problem, and the specific output you would like to get in that example.

Comment: I've attached a paint file of what the CSV file looks like and the bottom one is how I want the result to look like...sorry if i'm being unclear - i'm very new to this!!

Comment: :D we need to see an example for the actual CSV file, the text file that the program should read in order to generate the result you want. but keep the paint-ing it does help describe your problem

Comment: I won't be able to share that information as it is private to the company. I am an intern here and they've handed me a bash project - got no experience so I'm feeling a bit lost haha .. this is for an ITRS dashboard btw

Comment: I understand that you cannot give real content, but you can take that schema and replace the titles with names from your favorite TV show and replace the values with arbitrary numbers and/or text. For instance, we need to know your fieldseperator. We also need to know if and where whitespace is allowed. etc. etc.

Comment: okay! I have updated the post - is this better?

Comment: :D we need to see an example for the actual CSV file, the text file that the program should read in order to generate the result you want. But meanwhile you have to possible answers. You should try them out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See how far this gets you

```
awk -F\; '
    {TMP = ""
     for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i == "") TMP = sprintf ("%s,%c", TMP, 64+i)
     print substr (TMP,2)
    }
' /test1.csv
B,F,H
A,G,H

A,C,F
```

Adapt the field separator if need be. Will fail beyond Column 26.

Adapted to the new requirements

```
    awk -F\; '
    NR == 1 {MX = split ($0, HDR)
             next
            }
            {TMP = ""
             for (i=1; i<=MX; i++) if ($i == "") TMP = sprintf ("%s,%s", TMP, HDR[i])
             print substr (TMP,2)
            }
    ' file
banana
rachel
banana
rachel,monica,chandler,joey,janice,banana
rachel,monica,chandler,joey,banana
```

Comment: Banana fields for Rachel grew :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one too:

```
BEGIN {FS=OFS=","}
{
    if (NR == 1)
        split($0, hdr)

        if (nr) {nr = 0; print("")}
        for(f=1; f<=NF; f++)
            if ($f == "") {
                if (!nr)
                    printf("%s", hdr[f])
                else
                    printf("%c%s", OFS, hdr[f])
                nr = 1
            }
}
```

Well, here is a special BANANA column implementation:

```
BEGIN {FS = OFS = ","}

NR == 1 {
        printf("%s%c%s\n", $0, OFS, "BANANA")
        split($0, hdr)
        next
}

{
        for(f = 1; f <= NF; f++)
            if ($f == "") {
                printf("%s%c%s\n", $0, OFS, hdr[f])
                break
            }
}
```

Comment: You might want to check for the banana fields.

Comment: @RudiC Ahaha, you did everything superperfect already to finish his homework :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something along the lines of

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=";" }
NR==1 {
        for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) { heads[i]=$i; }
      }

      { for(i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
          if ($i == "") { printf "%s ",heads[i] }
        }
        print "";
      } 
'
```

This should shred the fields of the first row into an array `heads`. For every row that is not the first row, awk iterates over the columns and prints the name of the column, if the field is empty. Didn't have time to test though. May contain bugs. YMMV

Comment: You might want to check for the banana fields.

Comment: @RudiC I don't let anybody near my banana fields :D